# Delete from mysql using joins?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a database of 2 tables users and classes each user may have many classes so I added a third table called userClasses which had user ID and class ID , so when I want to delete the user from users table, I need to delete it from the UserClasse table too.

And I did that request :

```
    $id = $_GET['id']; // already passed through URL using GET method .

    $del = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM users,userClasses WHERE users.id= :id, userClasses.userID= :id");

    $del->bindParam(':id',$id);
    $del->execute();
```

But it won't DELETE! Nothing happens, is there any solution please & how ?

Comment: you can't use the same `:id` for two items they have to be different

Comment: @adil, I have rolled back your edit that made the question text "Nothing ... <gibberish>". If you can, deleting the question is the preferred method of getting rid of a question. However, since there's an existing answer, you may not be able to. In which case, take the negative rep and learn from it in the future. I've had the same thing happen to me ;)

Comment: Also, I might add that you could probably improve this question and get some upvotes to compensate for the downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

Your SQL is nonsense - where is the 'salleresp' table?

You can't delete a joined result set. Either declare your tables using [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) or run 2 delete queries - one for users and one for userClasses.

Comment: sorry it's userClasses  ! yes the userId in userClasses  table is a foreign key from id row in users table.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a foreign key constraint you will not be able to delete entries from both tables in one query.  However, if there isn't such a constraint, the following would work:

```
DELETE u.*, uc.* 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN userClasses uc 
ON u.id = uc.userID
WHERE u.id= :id
```